# Demonstrating Quantum effects with home experiments using green diode laser

Tags: specific-reference, home-experiment, laser

I would like to preform home experiments to demonstrate quantum effects to my kids. I need a list of experiments on Laser photons that could be easily conducted at home to demonstrate quantum mechanical effects. I'm not interested in experiments that can be explained by considering light as electromagnetic waves.

I would appreciate helpful suggestions or a good reference.

Comment: Hi turkistany - list questions like this are not appropriate on this site. It would be a fine thing to bring up in [chat], though.

Answer (score 0):

The best(and cheap) experiment to perform at home to show quantum mechanical nature of light(interference), is Young's double slit diffraction experiment.

Found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment